# How to calculate the output size of a convoluitonal layer in YOLO?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, computer-science, yolo, conv-neural-network

[image: YOLO Architecture]

This is the architecture of YOLO. I am trying to calculate the output size of each layer myself, but I can't get the size as described in the paper.

For example, in the first Conv Layer, the input size is 448x448 but it uses a 7x7 filter with stride 2, but according to this equation **W2=(W1−F+2P)/S+1 = (448 - 7 + 0)/2 + 1**, I can't get an integer result, so the filter size seems to be unsuitable to the input size.

So anyone can explain this problem? Did I miss something or misunderstand the YOLO architecture?

Comment: what paper are you talking about? at least provide a link. Did you misunderstand the YOLO architecture? how did you understand it?

Comment: @Piglet the paper is https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02640

Comment: I would use a framework that does this computation for you, for example Keras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hawx Won said, the input image has been added extra 3 paddings, and here is how it works from the source code.

For convolution layers, if pad is enabled, The padding value of each layer will be calculated by:

```
# In parser.c
if(pad) padding = size/2;

# In convolutional_layer.c
l.pad = padding;
```

Where `size` is the shape of the filter.

So, for the first layer: **padding = size/2 = 7/2=3**

Then the output of first convolutional layer should be:

**output_w = (input_w+2*pad-size)/stride+1 = (448+6-7)/2+1 = 224**

**output_h = (input_h+2*pad-size)/stride+1 = (448+6-7)/2+1 = 224**

Answer (score 2):

Well, I spent some time learning the source code, and learned about that the input image has added extra 3 paddings on top,down,left and right side of the image, so the image size becomes **(448+2x3)=454**, the out put size of valid padding should be calculated in this way:
**Output_size=ceil((W-F+1)/S)=(454-7+1)/2=224**, therefore, output size should be **224x224x64**

I hope this could be helpful